# Writing a Conditional For Loop to Sum a Subset of a List and Return Binary Value

Tags: python

I want to focus on a moving window of `k` in the lyst below, starting on the left and stopping one element short of the right edge.  I want to take the sum of the 3 (k) items in the window. If the sum is `>= k/2`, append the value of 1 to the list "pred", otherwise append 0 to the list.

Here is my code so far:

```
lyst=[1,0,1,0,1]
k=3
pred=[]

for x in range(0, len(lyst)-k):
    sumList=sum(lyst)
    if sumList >= k/2:
        pred.append(1)
    else:
        pred.append(0)
print(pred)
```

I know my `sumList` item is the issue here.  I just need to adjust that so it generally sums `k` items to create 2 (that's len(lyst)-k) new values to `pred`. Each value will either be 0 or 1 depending on the condition.

Output should be:

```
pred=[1, 0]
```

Output I'm getting now:

```
pred=[1,1]
```

Comment: Your description doesn't parse in English; you're missing punctuation and perhaps a few words.  Please show the output you expect and the output you get.  Describe the process with respect to those values.  That should clarify the problem.

Comment: *Why* is the output `0, 1`?  It looks to me like it shoudl be the opposite.  If we add the first 3 positions, the sum is more than k/2; the sum of positions 1-3 is less.  Therefore, the output would be `[1, 0]`.  What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: Right but we aren't adding the sums to the new list "pred." The assignment is to add a binary value to the list "pred" if the sum matches the condition. The condition is if the sum of the 3 items before x is greater than k/2, add either 0 or 1 to the list.

Comment: I'm not adding the sums to `pred`; I'm trying to follow your instructions.  The first three elements sum as `1+0+1 = 2`  This is more than `k/2`, so the result should be a `1`.  Your updates tell me this should be a `0`.  Similarly, the second is `0+1+0 = 1`, *less* than k/2, which should be a `0`.  I don't understand the process.

Comment: Sorry, user error. Pred should be [1,0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical part is taking *only* the required slice of `lyst` for your sum.  Your start position is the left end for `k` elements of `lyst`:

```
for start in range(0, len(lyst)-k):
    sumList = sum(lyst[start:start+k])
```

This will move a `k`-element window through `lyst`: `[1, 0, 1]`, then `[0, 1, 0]`.  These are greater than `k/2` (yielding a `1`) and less (for a `0`).

Output:

```
[1, 0]
```

---

**ADVANCED IMPLEMENTATION**

You can build a list comprehension from the inside out, using the code in your (now repaired) loop.

```
lyst=[1,1,0,0,1]
k=3
pred = [int(sum(lyst[start:start+k]) >= k/2)
            for start in range(0, len(lyst)-k)]
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! I knew it was the sum giving me grief.

Comment: @gboffi: It took some dialogue to get the idea.  I edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

First you  have an error in your code:

`for x in range(0, len(lyst)-k)` will iterate over the `len(lyst)-k` first items not the last ones.

You can read about [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function to see how it works. Said that you can use [slices](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) in order to take the sum of the elements you want.

You code can be changed as:

```
for x in range(len(lyst) - 1, len(lyst) - k, -1):
    sumList=sum(lyst[x-k:x])
```